# RTC DS3231 get reset

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rtc, time

The RTC module ZS-042 get suddenly reset and show default values (2000/0/0) with no possibility to change it no matter what. The reset can occur after uploading a new sketch (I'm using ESP32) or while running.

Just after I unplug the module from ESP32, reconnect it (SCL, SDA, VCC, GND) and upload new sketch it's back to operate normally.

The reset looks like:

[image]

The code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include "WiFi.h"

const char* ssid     = "****";
const char* password = "*******";
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";

RTC_DS3231 rtc; //class RTC_DS3231 

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void setup () {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("");

  configTime(0, 0, ntpServer);
  setenv("TZ", "IST-2IDT,M3.4.4/26,M10.5.0", 1);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("CONNECTED!");

  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop () {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();

  Serial.print(now.year());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day());
  Serial.print(" (");
  Serial.print(now.dayOfTheWeek());
  Serial.print(") ");
  Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
  Serial.println();

 if (touchRead(15) < 10)    // touch pin 15 to update time & date
 {
  struct tm timeinfo;
  getLocalTime(&timeinfo);
  int day = timeinfo.tm_mday;
  int month = timeinfo.tm_mon + 1;
  int year = timeinfo.tm_year + 1900;
  Serial.println(day);
  Serial.println(month);
  Serial.println(year);
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(year, month, day, timeinfo.tm_hour, timeinfo.tm_min, 
  timeinfo.tm_sec));
  // begin Transmission with address 0x68 (DS3231_ADDRESS)
 }

 Serial.println();
 delay(1000);
 }
```

I'm using CR2032 3V and connect it to VCC=3.3V of the ESP.

I read that maybe the supply voltage is not sufficient but I'm not sure because usually it's work fine till the sudden reset occur (can occur once in a two weeks or more). I tried to connect VCC=5V without the battery and still the same problem (get reset once in a while).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this line: *"I'm using CR2032 3V and connect it to VCC=3.3V of the ESP"* Your battery should be inserted in socket of the ZS-042 module, not on Vcc. Otherwise, the RTC should reset.

Comment: The battery inserted to the socket, and the pins connected to ESP32 are SCL, SDA, VCC, GND. Still i get the strange values of 2000/0/0 without possibility to change it until i unplug the RTC from the ESP32 and reconnect it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you must put time to eeprom.

```
// get the offset we stored our data from address zero
uint8_t address = RtcEeprom.GetMemory(0);
if (address != stringAddr)
{
   // Serial.print("address didn't match ");
   // Serial.println(address);
}

{
    // get the size of the data from address 1
    uint8_t count = RtcEeprom.GetMemory(1);
    uint8_t buff[64];

    // get our data from the address with the given size
    uint8_t gotten = RtcEeprom.GetMemory(address, buff, count);

    if (gotten != count ||
        count != sizeof(data) - 1) // remove the extra null terminator strings add
    {
        //Serial.print("something didn't match, count = ");
        //Serial.print(count, DEC);
        //Serial.print(", gotten = ");
        //Serial.print(gotten, DEC);
        //Serial.println();
    }
    //Serial.print("data read (");
    //Serial.print(gotten);
    //Serial.print(") = \"");
    for (uint8_t ch = 0; ch < gotten; ch++)
    {
        //Serial.print((char)buff[ch]);
    }
   
}
```